# Search column in database Microsoft sql PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have made a form for searching my site and the php code that im trying to use looks like this

```
if (isset($_GET['search']))
{
$search = $_GET['search'];
$tsql5 = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE blog_title LIKE '%:search%'";
$stmt6 = $conn->prepare($tsql5);
$stmt6->execute (array($search));
while($search_result = $stmt6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) )
{ 
echo '$search_result[0]'; 
and so on...
```

From all the examples etc that i have found it should be working? when i press the search button i get to mysite.se/index.php?search=searchword

but i get no results when i know im searching for a word that do exists in a blog_title column... am i missing something here?

EDIT: might wanna add that im using microsoft sql server not mysql

Comment: You should read about, understand and utilize parameterized queries before little bobby tables to visit.

Comment: @SeanLange the OP is trying to use parameterized queries, just mis-using them.

Comment: @chris85 cool. I am not a php expert (well actually I can barely spell it) but it doesn't look like other php snippets with parameterized queries I have seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a something like `:search`, not your actual term. (I'd think this actually throw an error about mismatched bound terms to placeholders.) The placeholder needs to be on its own. Also when binding you need to use the bound name in the binding. Try:

```
$tsql5 = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE blog_title LIKE :search";
$stmt6 = $conn->prepare($tsql5);
$stmt6->execute (array(':search' => '%' . $search . '%'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining, it worked as intended :)

Comment: just out of curiosity, can i do like $tsql5 = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE * LIKE :search"; as in search all the columns?

Comment: Nope, you could list all columns with `or`s; or you could look at full text searching. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx